# Cypress automation: multiple cy.get elements in one function

Tags: cypress

I have a function:

```
checkWebElemAndAssert(...elements) {
    for (const element of elements) {
        element.should('be.visible').click().should('be.checked');
    }
}
```

and i use it within another function:

```
checkRegisterValues = () => {
    let maleCheckBox = cy.get('input[value=Male]');
    let femaleCheckBox = cy.get('input[value=FeMale]');
    let cricketCheckBox = cy.get('#checkbox1');
    let registerElemList = [maleCheckBox, femaleCheckBox, cricketCheckBox];
    this.browserUtils.checkWebElemAndAssert(...registerElemList);
    return this;
}
```

The problem is that when i use checkRegisterValues() it uses for each action the last element: cricketCheckBox. Any hints on what is wrong? i would expect that the action is made for each element and not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing in the array like this?

```
    this.browserUtils.checkWebElemAndAssert(registerElemList);
```

You can also print out

```
checkWebElemAndAssert(...elements) {
   console.log(elements);
   for (const element of elements) {
      element.should('be.visible').click().should('be.checked');
  }
}
```

and see what you are passing in

Answer (score -1):

ok so i read a bit more and made this:

```
checkWebElemAndAssert2(elements) {
    cy.get(elements).each(($list) => {
        cy.get($list).click({ multiple: true }).should('be.checked')
    })
}
```

Basically in elements when i call checkWebElemAndAssert2 i will give the list identifier. Seems to work but not sure meets the standard.

```
checkRegisterValues = () => {
    let myList = 'input[type=radio]';
    this.browserUtils.checkWebElemAndAssert2(myList);
    return this;
}
```